# Use the page title in the plugin

Tags: plugins

I have many WordPress pages,  I am using only one shortcode in those pages, For example the content of page1 is [shortcode name="page1"],

content of page2 is [shortcode name="page2"],

content of page3 is [shortcode name="page3"]

Is it possible that I don't need to specify the name attribute in the shortcode and I can just specify [shortcode] and it takes the title of the page as the name attribute automatically

For example, in plugin, i could write something like this

```
function shortcode($atts)
 {
 extract(shortcode_atts(array(
'name' => "**title of the page**",
   ) , $atts));

  ......


  }

add_shortcode('short_code', 'short_code');
```

Comment: Are you looking for the 'get_the_title()' function? - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) function to get the current post's title in your shortcode. If you want it to work only on pages, you can combine it with `is_page()`:

```
function shortcode($atts) {

    extract( 
        shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'name' => get_the_title(),
            ) , 
        $atts) 
    );

    // Rest of your code

}

add_shortcode('short_code', 'short_code');
```

You can use a PHP shorthand conditional as follows:

```
'name' => ( is_page() ) ? get_the_title() : 'Your else goes here' ;
```